# Product of symmetric matrices equals zero matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

Let $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be *symmetric* matrices.

Assume that $Q=\left[q_{1}, \ldots, q_{r}\right]$ is an $n \times r$ matrix whose columns form an *orthonormal basis* of

$$
\operatorname{ker} X := \{ v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid  Xv = 0 \} \,.
$$

---

I am working on proving the following claim:

If

$$
X Z = 0_{n,n}
$$

then there exists a *symmetrix* matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}$ such that

$$
Z=Q Y Q^{\top} \,.
$$

---

This claim is part of a lemma from a paper I am currently reading. In this paper the above claim is proved by the following:

$X Z=0_{n,n}$ implies that

$$
\operatorname{range} Z \subset \operatorname{ker} X=\operatorname{span}\left\{q_{1}, \ldots, q_{r}\right\} \,,
$$

where $\operatorname{range} Z := \{ u \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \mid \exists v \in \mathbb{R}^{n} \, \text{ s.t. } \, Zv = u  \}$.

This implies that

\begin{equation}
Z \in \operatorname{span}(\{q_{i} q_{j}^{\top}+q_{j} q_{i}^{\top} \mid i, j=1, \ldots, r\})=\left\{Q Y Q^{\top} \mid Y \text{ is a symmetric } r \times r \text{ matrix}\right\}
\end{equation}

---

I am not sure how to proceed from here. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't change the symbols in your question in a way that renders the existing answer unreadable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $Z=[z_1,\dots,z_n]$ with column vectors $z_j$. The assumption says that $Xz_j=0$ for each $j$. Thus $z_j\in \ker(X)$, which means that $z_j$ is a linear combination of $q_1,\dots, q_r$. Thus there exists a vector $a_j\in M_{r\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $$z_j=Qa_j.$$
Set $A=[a_1,\dots,a_n]\in M_{r\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, we get $$Z=QA.$$
This implies that $Z^t=A^tQ^t$. Since $Z=Z^t$, we get $XA^tQ^t=0$. Note that $Q^tQ=I_r$. Thus $XA^t=0$. In particular, each column vector in $A^t$ is in $\ker(X)$. Repeat the above process, it is easy to find a matrix $Y\in M_{r\times r}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^t=QY^t.$ Thus $A=YQ^t$ and
$$Z=QA=QYQ^t.$$
Since $Z=Z^t$, we have $QY^tQ^t=QYQ^t$. Using $Q^tQ=I_r$ again, we can obtain that $Y=Y^t$.

Comment: @ Q. Zhang: Many thanks for your answer. If you let me know which institution you are affiliated with, i would like to mention you in the acknowledgement of my thesis.

Comment: @mathsstudent98 It is my pleasure if it helps. Also thanks for your kind words and for trying to mention me in your thesis. But it is not necessary. If you really would like to, probably you can mention this website, which is really very helpful. I did it once in a paper. Regards.

Comment: I will use the cite button/function which I just discovered. Again, many thanks.